# Is there any solution to show a series of images with different sizes next to each other and all have the same height without breaking image?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

My problem is that I need to show a series of images (a maximum of 5) next to each other, but the images have different sizes, for example an image that is a square (150x150) is looking bigger next to the one which is a rectangle. I need to show all of them in a same height without breaking image resolution. It's important to say that I have 5 divs with img tag inside them, the idea is to have 1 div and make it dynamic, so an editor could put its own images.

Technologies that i'm using: Bootstrap 4

This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k21NY.jpg
And this is how it should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1f04.jpg

I have tried putting a max-width of 75px to the div that contains the img but there are parts of the image that are not shown.

```css
.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.imgbox {
  max-width: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.title {
  color: #142834;
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.link {
  margin-top: 34px;
}

.img-styles {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-9 col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-xl-10">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex scrolling-wrapper-flexbox justify-content-between">
        <div class="imgbox m-0 d-flex align-items-center"><img class="img-styles" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Zanella.png" alt="img1"></div>
        <div class="imgbox m-0 d-flex align-items-center"><img class="img-styles" src="http://www.uniminuto.edu/documents/991974/8397593/logo_issuu.png/081442f2-a9a8-4041-b0ef-9c47939df481?version=1.0&t=1511884354155&imagePreview=1" alt="img2"></div>
        <div class="imgbox m-0 d-flex align-items-center"><img class="img-styles" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Logo_Globosat.svg/500px-Logo_Globosat.svg.png" alt="img3"></div>
        <div class="imgbox m-0 d-flex align-items-center"><img class="img-styles" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Logo_MAM.png" alt="img4"></div>
        <div class="imgbox m-0 d-flex align-items-center"><img class="img-styles" src="https://www.pngeiti.org.pg/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cropped-favicon-270x270.png" alt="img5"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#" class="link">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that all div and img tags have the same behavior because later on I want to make it dynamic and leave 1 div, so the editor could enter his own images.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a height? It may be challenging with each image having a different aspect ratio, but if the height is set and the width is auto you might be able to get something close to what you are going for. I would typically host and scale all the images to the same size if I was worried about weird scaling. It will also help load times when you aren't displaying an 500px wide image at 150px.

Comment: If for example i put a height of 75px in img-styles i would fix the problem of the square images that looks bigger than the other ones, but the one that says globosat doesnt look very good, it look a bit tight.

Comment: I have a solution in Javascript. you can get the original height of each image in JS using `img.naturalHeight`. If you get all images in an array and get the lowest height and then set that value to all images `height`, it will solve your problem without any compomise. If you are interested, I can write a function and put it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap 4, this both solutions should work:

```css
.bootstrap-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
  align-items: baseline;
}
.bootstrap-grid img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 120px;
  object-fit: contain;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.icons-flex > .container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.icons-flex > .container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 20%; 
  text-align: center;
}
.icons-flex > .container > div > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center mt-4">Bootstrap Grid</h2>
    <div class="row mt-3 bootstrap-grid">
        <div class="grid"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Zanella.png"></div>
        <div class="grid"><img src="http://www.uniminuto.edu/documents/991974/8397593/logo_issuu.png/081442f2-a9a8-4041-b0ef-9c47939df481?version=1.0&t=1511884354155&imagePreview=1"></div>
        <div class="grid"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Logo_Globosat.svg/500px-Logo_Globosat.svg.png"></div>
        <div class="grid"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Logo_MAM.png"></div>
        <div class="grid"><img src="https://www.pngeiti.org.pg/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cropped-favicon-270x270.png"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="text-center mt-4">Flex</h2>
    <div class="row mt-3 flex icons-flex">
        <div class="container">
            <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Zanella.png"></div>
            <div><img src="http://www.uniminuto.edu/documents/991974/8397593/logo_issuu.png/081442f2-a9a8-4041-b0ef-9c47939df481?version=1.0&t=1511884354155&imagePreview=1"></div>
            <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Logo_Globosat.svg/500px-Logo_Globosat.svg.png"></div>
            <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Logo_MAM.png"></div>
            <div><img src="https://www.pngeiti.org.pg/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cropped-favicon-270x270.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope that helps. Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SusanaSanz/f3xcL7s5/15/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! The flex option was exactly what i needed. I only had to set div width to 175px instead of 20% so in devices i could scroll logos in both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `max-height` property in `.img-styles` (or on the `div` around the `img` tag, but this would not work if you place all images in one `div`)

If you want the images to fully have the same height, you should drop `max-width` from both `.img-styles` and `.imgbox`. In this case you would also need images with a height that is bigger than the specified `max-height`. This result could result in some very wide images.

In your mock-up of how it should look the height of some elements is still smaller, so I would keep the `max-width` property to keep the width of some elements under control. In this case the actual height of your image matters less, since not everything will have the same height anyway.

Comment: Adding a `max-height` value isn't a good solution since he doesn't know what will be the height of the smallest image in his list.

Comment: True, I've clarified my answer a bit to incorporate this

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help, i could resolve the problem with flex option that was mentioned above.